# Updating and cross-querying tables with non-distinct values?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, sql-update

I'm working with IMDb data to find out full crew information of a number of chosen films.

I've isolated my dataset of films according to my requirements. I now have a table `movie (movie_id, movie_title, movie_year)`, with 476 rows.

Then I made a list of all distinct individuals who have worked on those films, totalling 44,706 rows stored in table `person (person_id, person_name)`.

Now I am trying to put together a table `crew (person_id, movie_id, role_id)`, where each row would hold a unique combination of *person_id* and *movie_id*, illustrating the fact that the same person could have worked on a number of films.

First I created the table and populated it with non-distinct instances of persons as such:

```
CREATE TABLE crew
(
    person_id INTEGER,
    movie_id INTEGER,
    role_id INTEGER,
);

INSERT INTO crew (person_id)
    SELECT cast_info.person_id
    FROM cast_info
    INNER JOIN movie
    ON cast_info.movie_id=movie.movie_id;
```

At this point I should mention that `cast_info (id, person_id, movie_id, role_id)` is the master table, which holds information on all existing combinations of persons, movies and roles hosted on IMDb, 50,691,107 rows in total.

After running the above code, I ended up with 61,842 rows in the *crew* table. Double-checking `SELECT count(distinct person_id) FROM crew;` tells me that there are 44,706 unique persons, as in my original *person* table.

Now I'm struggling to fill the *movie_id* and *role_id* columns in the *crew* table. I tried the following code:

```
UPDATE crew
SET movie_id = 
    (SELECT cast_info.movie_id
    FROM cast_info, movie
    WHERE cast_info.movie_id=movie.movie_id)
WHERE crew.person_id IN 
    (SELECT cast_info.person_id 
    FROM cast_info, person
    WHERE cast_info.person_id=person.person_id);
```

All that did was fill the *crew.movie_id* column with the same *movie_id* repeated for each row.

How do I update my table to make sure that for each non-distinct *person_id* there are only those cases of *movie_id* which appear in my *movie* table? I'm working on SQLite, which doesn't support INNER JOINs on UPDATE statements.

Comment: Populate all columns at the same time.  Inserting duplicate values and then attempting the update is not the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be helpful if you shared the schema for 'cast_info'. It is unclear why you aren't populating crew with movie_id from the start since you clearly have it available to you since you use it in this JOIN ON clause:

```
ON cast_info.movie_id=movie.movie_id;
```

You could update your initial insert clause to be:

```
INSERT INTO crew (person_id, movie_id)
SELECT cast_info.person_id, cast_info.movie_id
FROM cast_info
INNER JOIN movie
ON cast_info.movie_id=movie.movie_id;
```

That would insert both the person_id and movie_id at the same time.

It is not clear where you would pull role information from but I'd imagine it would be simple to populate that given the person_id and movie_id would now be available for use in whatever JOIN is needed.

Comment: To be honest with you I didn't populate the crew table with everything from the start because I'm just starting out with SQL and I didn't realise that an INSERT INTO could work with several columns at once. Your suggestion worked perfectly, thank you!